# C++ Missing Initializer error

Tags: c++, debugging

I am getting this error during compile time (g++ 4.4.6):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
main.cpp:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
main.cpp:33: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘for’
main.cpp:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
main.cpp:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘for’
main.cpp:33: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
main.cpp:36: error: could not convert ‘((list != 0u) ? (list->SortedList::~SortedList(), operator delete(((void*)list))) : 0)’ to ‘bool’
main.cpp:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
main.cpp:37: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘return’
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
#include "SortedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SortedList *list = new SortedList();

    Student create[100];
    int num = 100000;

    for (Student &x : create) { // <--Line 27
        x = new Student(num);
        num += 10;
    }

    for (Student &x : create)
    list->insert(&x);

    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

Anybody who possibly knows the source of the error would be of great help. Also, Student and SortedList are objects which are declared in their .h files.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: I am somewhat new to C++ so, if you could explain what -std=c++0x does or means that would be much appreciated

Comment: @PatMurray: ranged-based for loops(your line 27) are a C++11 feature. You have to pass `-std=c++0x` or (-std=c+11 in newer versions) to the compiler to be able to use c++11 features. However, I would recommend upgrading your compiler to a newer version first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page on GCC's website](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), range-based for is only available in g++ 4.6 and up, so you'll have to convert your code to a normal `for` loop or use `std::for_each` or something, or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: alright, that would make sense. Ill revise my code and see what happens

Comment: The normal for-loops compiled properly. Thanks.

Comment: @PatMurray good, glad you got it working. I would really appreciate it if you would accept this answer since it answered your question, because I am only 5 reputation away from having 200 today with only about an hour left :)

Comment: @ildjarn but they do make you get 200 rep in a day, which means I will be one day closer to the legendary badge.

Comment: @SethCarnegie : Ah, I was under the impression that it had to be 200 _upvote_ rep per day for Epic and Legendary, but you're right -- a quick glance at meta proves otherwise.